# limit resources for authenticated user in flask or Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, flask

Currently im planning to distribute resources such as memory, cpu and other resources based on the authenticated user.

I tried to search on how can i implement it but i only managed to find rate limit for request and ability to gain information of memory and cpu using psutil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide examples in both Flask and Django for limiting resources for authenticated users based on their resource requirements.

**Flask Example:**

In Flask, you can use the **psutil library** to get information about system resources and allocate them based on user requirements. Here's an example of how you can implement a middleware in Flask to limit **CPU and memory** resources for authenticated users:

```
import psutil
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def limit_resources():
# Get the authenticated user
user = request.headers.get('Authorization')

# Get the user's resource requirements from the database
# In this example, we assume the resource requirements are stored in the user's profile
user_profile = UserProfile.query.filter_by(username=user).first()

# Set the CPU limit for the user
cpu_limit = user_profile.cpu_limit
psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)
psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=True)
if psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None) > cpu_limit:
    abort(503, description="CPU usage limit exceeded")

# Set the memory limit for the user
memory_limit = user_profile.memory_limit
memory_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
if memory_usage > memory_limit:
    abort(503, description="Memory usage limit exceeded")
```

In this example, we use the **before_request decorator** to define a middleware that is executed before each request. The middleware gets the authenticated user from the request header and retrieves the user's resource requirements from the database. It then checks the CPU and memory usage using psutil and compares it with the user's resource requirements. If the usage exceeds the limit, it returns a **503 error**.

---

**Django Example:**

In Django, you can use the **django-cgroup package** to allocate resources to specific users or groups using cgroups. Here's an example of how you can implement resource limiting in Django using **django-cgroup**:

```
import psutil
from django_cgroup import Cgroup

def limit_resources(request):
   # Get the authenticated user
   user = request.user

# Get the user's resource requirements from the database
# In this example, we assume the resource requirements are stored in the user's profile
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

# Set the CPU limit for the user
cpu_limit = user_profile.cpu_limit
cgroup = Cgroup('cpu', user.username)
cgroup.set(cfs_quota_us=cpu_limit)

# Set the memory limit for the user
memory_limit = user_profile.memory_limit
cgroup = Cgroup('memory', user.username)
cgroup.set(mem_limit=memory_limit)
```

In this example, we define a function called **limit_resources** that is called for each authenticated user. The function retrieves the user's resource requirements from the database and sets the CPU and memory limits using **django-cgroup**. django-cgroup provides a simple interface for setting resource limits using cgroups.

---

**Keep** in mind that these examples are simplified and may need to be adapted to your specific use case. Additionally, you should carefully consider the resources you want to limit and how you want to allocate them, as this can have a significant impact on application performance and user experience.